# How do I rename a list of files whose names contain spaces and a sequentially changing number?

Tags: numbers, filenames, spaces

Say that I have a folder containing a list of Windows filenames that have spaces and numbers , where the number is different for each filename in the list.  How can I use the Command Prompt window's RENAME command (or other commands) to rename the list of files ?

**Example:**
I want to change a list of file names,

**From:**

My Photo 1.jpeg

My Photo 2.jpeg

.

.

.

My Photo 50.jpeg

**To:**

Your Photo 1.jpeg

Your Photo 2.jpeg

.

.

.

Your Photo 50.jpeg

Thank you.

Comment: If you are in ms windows, just select all files you want to rename, press F2 and put the name you want, windows will automatically add a number to each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do it in two DOS commands:

```
dir /b My*.jpeg >x.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %i in (x.txt) do ren "%i %j %k" "Your %j %k"
```

`ren My* Your*` **WILL NOT WORK PROPERLY**
you will end up with

> Yourhoto1.jpeg
>   Yourhoto2.jpeg
>   etc...

Comment: Hi Steve:  Thanks for the advice.  The first line of code works correctly - it produces a .txt file containing the jpeg photo file names.  I cannot get the second command to work.  Say that the .txt file has 4 file names in it. When I enter the second command, I see 4 lines, each showing the path to the folder containing the .txt file, with the old file name and new file name in quotes.  Example: C:\path> "Old Filename" "New Filename".  After each line, I get the following error message.  "The system cannot find the file specified."    I have checked my typing - still get the same error.

Comment: LOL. I just noticed you had a space between "Photo" and the number. I have modified the code to reflect that now.

Comment: Hi Steve: Your updated code worked great ! Now...tell me if I understand it correctly. You are looping (once) through the list of photo files in the file, x.txt, where the "tokens=1,2,3" specifies that there are 3 fields (parts) to each file name (ignoring the .jpeg part). And, as you loop through the list you replace the text string in the first field with "Your" while keeping the other two fields as they were; thus renaming the photo (.jpeg) files. The in (x.txt) specifies to use the x.txt file as input to the rename command.  Is "tokens" a keyword, or a user-defined variable like MyIndex ?

Comment: You got it! The tokens are separated by a space. "token" is a parsing key word. There are a boat load of things you can do with the "for" command. For a detailed look, see the TechNet article at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx

Comment: Thanks Steve ... For the link, and taking time to answer my questions.

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad that I could be of service. If this answered your question, be sure to mark this as answered.

Comment: Hey Steve:  I am trying to mark your answer as the Best answer, but the web page is not incrementing the counter between the up & down arrows.  The is a check mark next to both answers.. Prior to your second answer,  I had clicked on the first answer since you advised that it was wrong.  Then, you provided me with more detailed info on how to correctly perform the task.  I do not know if I am doing something wrong. I want to give you credit.  Currently, two answers are checked, but your detailed answer is THE solution.  What do the numbers between the arrows mean ? My question is rated -1.

Comment: The number between the arrows is the number of people who have voted a particular answer up or down, by clicking the up vote or down vote arrow. You and anyone else can do that for one or more answers, but you are only allowed one vote which you can change up or down. Below the down arrow, only you (the one asking the question) can see the greyed check mark which you can click (or unclick) to make it green, which selects an answer as the accepted choice. At any time, you can always change your mind a select another answer. I believe that when you mark a question answered, you can also up/down.

Comment: The -1 means that someone, somewhere, didn't like the question and voted down which costs them 1 reputation point and you two reputation points, only if you have that many to lose. People are fickle. I have answered questions where I have been down-voted and someone else posts the same answer after me and get voted up and marked as answered. Go figure. Anyway, I have found a lot of good answers on StackOverflow over the years, and me answering other people's question is my way of giving back whether I get credit or not. I'm just glad I could help.

Comment: Are you saying that I can only vote on one of the answers ?  I have only been able to vote on one answer.   I was able to give your detailed answer the "green check mark", but am still unable to give it a positive vote.

Comment: That's odd, you should be able to up/down vote on any and all answers as well as questions, whether you ask them or not. You can only give one green check mark to one answer to questions you have asked, though can always change your mind if a better answer comes along.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all files you want, press F2 and put the name you want, then press enter. Windows will put a number to each file, something like Your Photo (1).jpeg

If you want to use `rename` command just open the command prompt and put: `ren My* Your*`

Comment: Your rename command will NOT rename the files properly in the format in which the question was asked.

Comment: Steve's comment is correct about the above comment not formatting the file names properly. The advice given by Aguardientico just adds and index to the list of file names.  It does not rename a list of files that have numbers withing the file names.